# HTML/JS: Changing select option value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown select menu with two options. Basically im using JavaScript to get the value of the selected drop down option and pasting into a text area.
Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#pdSev').change(function () {
    $('#textarea').html($("#pdSev option:selected").text());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pdSev" name="pdSev">
  <option selected disabled class="test">Incident Severity</option>
  <option value="test">Test</option>
  <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>
<textarea id="textarea" class="textarea is-rounded has-fixed-size" placeholder="Example"></textarea>
```

So far this currently works as when I select an item from the select menu, the option value gets replicated into the texture field.

However, I want the option value to be replaced by a paragraph instead of just containing a word, for example:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

What would be the best way to do something like this in JS?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question and comments from another answer, here is how you can achieve what you are looking for;

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#pdSev').change(function () {
        if ($('#pdSev').val() == 'test') {
            var text = 'additional text';
            $('#textarea').val(text);
        } else if ($('#pdSev').val() == 'test2') {
            var text = 'text for this statement';
            $('#textarea').val(text);
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pdSev" name="pdSev">
  <option selected disabled class="test">Incident Severity</option>
  <option value="test">Test</option>
  <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>
<textarea id="textarea" class="textarea is-rounded has-fixed-size" placeholder="Example"></textarea>
```

From here you can keep building your `else if` statement and cater towards your needs. For example, if you added a `test3` you would update the `if statement` to look like;

```
if ($('#pdSev').val() == 'test') {
    var text = 'additional text';
    $('#textarea').val(text);
} else if ($('#pdSev').val() == 'test2') {
    var text = 'text for this statement';
    $('#textarea').val(text);
} else if ($('#pdSev').val() == 'test3') {
    var text = 'here is a new statement';
    $('#textarea').val(text);
}
```

Just beware the difference between `.val()` and `.text()`.

`.val()` will look inside the VALUE, where `.text()` will look for the TEXT between the option tag; as follows;

```
<option value="VALUE">TEXT</option>
```

So in the `if statement` I've provided, it is placing the `.text()` value in the textbox - but if you want it to place the `.val()` value in the textbox just update where I have `.text()` to be `.val()` - if this makes sense?

Comment: Thank you so much @Dexterians you are the best! This was the biggest help.

How do I exclude the value "test" or "test2" to be included in the textarea? Basically I only want whatever is in var text

Comment: @AyushLal - Just change ``$('#textarea').html($("#pdSev option:selected").text() + " : " + text);`` to be ``$('#textarea').html(text);`` inside the ``if statements`` - I've edited my answer to show you.

Comment: You're welcome! And please don't forget to mark the answer as the solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

In this example I've set the `value` of the `test` `option` to the paragraph.

The `textarea` now contains the value instead of the text.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    $('option[value="test"]').val(text);

    $('#pdSev').change(function () {
        $('#textarea').html($("#pdSev option:selected").val());
    })
});
```

```html
<body>
  <select id="pdSev" name="pdSev">
    <option selected disabled class="test">Incident Severity</option>
    <option value="test">Test</option>
    <option value="test2">Test2</option>
  </select>
  <textarea id="textarea" class="textarea is-rounded has-fixed-size" placeholder="Example"></textarea>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That looks pretty good although wouldn't there need to be a if statement or something because if the user selects "Test" I want it to have a different body of text compared to "Test2"

Comment: @AyushLal - you never stated that in your original question. Nor have you mentioned where this paragraph should be coming from. However you could write an IF-STATEMENT that if a certain select value is selected, it can input the appropriate paragraph.

Comment: @Dexterians Yeah sorry I wasn't specific enough. the paragraph is static so in theory another variable could contain the paragraph. How would I go about setting up an if-statement in there?

Comment: @AyushLal - check my answer, is that what you are after?